# Relation between finite stable rank and IBN (invariant basis number)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

For R is any ring has an identity, we known if R has stable rank one, then R is "weakly finite" (or "stably finite," all matrix rings over R are Dedekind finite) and this implies R has IBN .

But when stable rank of R is two (or greater than, but finite) in general R is not Dedekind finite. Then R has IBN? I tried to prove it but I had many difficulties.

So do every rings has finite stable rank is IBN ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi: sorry for the elementary question, but I have to ask. From my investigation it seems like the term "stable rank 1" might be synonymous with another term used now "Stable range 1". Is this right? It looks like Bass used the rank version originally and this may have stuck around in $K$ theory, but I have more often encountered "stable range" in my readings. I just want to make sure I'm not thinking of the wrong thing. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the answer to my last question is affirmative, the question would be "if $R$ has stable range $n$ for and $n$ with $1<n<\infty$, does $R$ necessarily have IBN?"

Comment: And if you've never seen [this paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2057777516781321305&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39) before, it's a good read :)

Comment: Thank you very much! What you said is what I want to express. Because I quiet bad at English so I didn't express exactly what to say. I will study the document that you sent me. I hope if I have some difficulties, I can contact you.
Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi "rschwieb": I've read the document that you sent me but still have not found the answer to my problem. In the article, Lam mentions stable rank of rings and some of related issues but he have not proven " if $ R $ has stable range $ n $ and $n$ with $1<n<\infty$, then $R$ has IBN".
So you can help me how to prove " A ring $ R $ of finite stable rank has IBN" ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with stable finiteness, and I don't see an obvious path to prove it, and I haven't ever heard the answer otherwise. I'm afraid I don't have any more help left to offer :)

Comment: That result has been mentioned in "Handbook of incidence geometry" by Veldkamp, and Cohn also mentioned that problem. But none of them  provided the specific proof. I'm looking for material for that matter. Unfortunately when you don't study much about it. But I also would like to thank you for helping  me. Wish you always happy :)

Comment: Do you happen to know the page in the Handbook where it appears? Or where Cohn mentions it? I would be grateful for the pointers. Regards

Comment: In Handbook, Veldkamp mentions it at page 1040, prop. 2.6. And Vavilov told me that Cohn also mentions it but he did not remember   that article. So I'm hoping to find documents that Cohn mentioned about it.

Comment: By the way, I think there is an error in your first paragraph. Dedekind finiteness does not imply IBN. In fact there is an example of a domain which does not have the IBN (but domains are all Dedekind finite.) Regards

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake. Weakly finiteness implies IBN, not Dedekind finiteness. Thank you for editing my error. So what ideas you have to prove that problem? How can show that "If ring R of finite stable rank has IBN"?

Comment: My answer to that is still "I don't know much about stable range and don't have any ideas." I went ahead and fixed the error we discussed. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you for fixing my mistakes and so sorry if I bothered you. Kind regards.

Comment: Not bothered at all: I do like the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask has a positive answer: If a ring has finite Bass stable rank, then it has IBN. The reasons are as follows, and the references below are  in [this paper](http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/open_files/2079_Rieffel-StableRank.pdf) of Rieffel. We define
$$
Lg_m(R) = \{(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_m)\in R^m : Ra_1+Ra_2+\ldots + Ra_m = R\}
$$
Rieffel shows that :

1. [Discussion preceding Theorem 4.5] If $m\geq Bsr(R)+1$, then $GL_m(R)$ acts transitively on $Lg_m(R)$
2. [Proposition 10.5] If $GL_m(R)$ acts transitively on $Lg_m(R)$ and $W$ is a projective left $R$-module such that $W\oplus R \cong R^m$, then $W\cong R^{m-1}$.

Now the result follows from the familiar [Eilenberg swindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle): Suppose $Bsr(A)<\infty$ and $R$ does not have IBN, then choose the smallest $n\geq 1$ such that there is $m>n$ with $R^m \cong R^n$. From this it follows that
$$
R^n \cong R^{m+k(m-n)} \quad\forall k\geq 0
$$
So choose $k$ such that $m+k(m-n) \geq Bsr(A)+1$, then by (1) and (2), one has
$$
R^{n-1} \cong R^{m+k(m-n)-1}
$$
This contradicts the minimality of $n$, thus completing the proof.